# How should I manage and reference many images files in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing a reference iPhone app that will contain many photos (ball park estimate of 75-100 photos). All of the photos will be stored locally along with at least one or two other versions of these photos in different image sizes representing the same image.

As a newbie to iPhone (and C) development, I'm unsure as to the best way to store these images for reference in the application. Is it possible to create folders/packages/bundles for them to live in?

FWIW, the app is run from an XML file, although I am considering a SQLite database as it is becoming harder to maintain with XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to write the image files to your applications' documents folder. You come up with a name for each file (or obtain it from XML), and then you use methods for dealing with image classes to obtain jpgs/pngs and save the files. You maintain references to the filenames strings elsewhere, persisting those in a .plist or archiving them in a dictionary (again, storing that archive in your documents folder).

CoreData now allows you to store files externally (which is better than storing larger images directly in SQLite) but it will manage and track them for you. That'slightly more sophisticated, but since XCode bundles CoreData templates, you can put those together very quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use The concept of Lazy Loading to download all images and save them in to root directory...All The best!!!